# Azure Integration account AS2 sync MDN issue

Tags: integration, azure-logic-apps, actionscript-2

I am performing a POC using Azure Integration account AS2. I have an issue with sending the sync MDN Message back.
I am using Mendelson to perform the testing

- Sending a signed and encrypted message to Azure Logic App **works**
- Decoding the message and validation **works**
- Sending the sync MDN back is giving an error in Mendelson **Issue**

Message send back by Logic App
[image: sync response]

[image: medelson response]

[image: AS2 Flow]

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue:

Response Body should be:

"body": "@base64ToString(body('Decode_AS2_message')?['OutgoingMdn']?['Content'])"